# Apache2 Won't Start: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: ssl-certificate, port, apache2, nextcloud

I've been trying to use Apache2 to put an SSL certificate on my Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS for Nextcloud, and I can't even get a far as to start Apache. I keep getting this error:

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pb9I.png)

I've looked up solutions to this and found about a hundred of them, each of them not working, or I just don't know how to solve it properly.

Help would be much appreciated, I've been suck on this for a few days now. :(

Answer (score 1):

there is already something bound to that port, that's why apache complains.

Try this to find out what is using port 80/tcp:

```
# ss --listening --tcp --numeric --processes
```

you should get a list of open listening sockets with the local address:port combination and the process that has opened each of them. Find out which one has opened port 80, stop that process and start apache again, it should work.

Comment: The service is "httpd", and I've seen it before. It's affiliated with Nextcloud. How would I stop it, or should I stop it?

Comment: then you should restart httpd, nextcloud uses it and it's already started

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me is:

- allocate in this path `/snap/nextcloud` use `unlink` to remove all link in this location.
- use `ps -edaf | grep http` and `kill -9` all `httpd` processes.

Answer (score 0):

[Per Nextcloud](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/17/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html#enabling-ssl)

**Enabling SSL**

You can use Nextcloud over plain HTTP, but we strongly encourage you to use SSL/TLS to encrypt all of your server traffic, and to protect user’s logins and data in transit.

Apache installed under Ubuntu comes already set-up with a simple self-signed certificate. All you have to do is to enable the ssl module and the default site.

Open a terminal and run:

```
a2enmod ssl
a2ensite default-ssl
service apache2 reload
```

You can also may want to put your instance into [maintenance mode](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/17/admin_manual/maintenance/upgrade.html#maintenance-mode)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @vidarlo it's the instructions for adding SSL to Nextfloud using apache2.

Comment: Yes. But how does it answer the question given the error message the user is struggling with?

Comment: he's specifically said he's be trying to put "Apache2 to put an SSL certificate on my Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS for Nextcloud."